# Spring boot actuator metrics for Prometheus in Consul Connect

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, consul, service-discovery

I have a spring boot application running in a Nomad cluster with Consul Connect enabled.

```
network {
  mode = "bridge"
}

service {
  name = "api"
  port = "9966"

  connect {
    sidecar_service {}
  }
}
```

There is no port mapping defined and the API is reachable only within consul service mesh through the proxy. Now I have prometheus running in the same cluster. How does prometheus discover the individual API instances and scrape metrics out of it. I used the below config. But without having a mapping port in the host level, it is not able to reach the individual API instance.

```
- job_name: 'actuator'
    metrics_path: /api/actuator/prometheus
    consul_sd_configs:
    - server: '{{ env "NOMAD_IP_prometheus_ui" }}:8500'
      services: ['api']
```

How to solve this problem? What is general practice to scrape metrics from a spring boot application running inside a service mesh with no host port mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it. Nomad has an option to expose a particular endpoint via sidecar proxy without mTLS authentication. The use case of this option is specifically for health check or metrics.

https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/job-specification/expose#expose-examples

The `expose` stanza inside `connect` stanza helps to achieve this.

```
connect {
        sidecar_service {
          proxy {
            expose {
              path {
                path             =  "/actuator/prometheus"
                protocol         =  "http"
                local_path_port  =  9966
                listener_port    =  "metrics"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: The expose path parameter is also documented in slightly more detail at <https://www.consul.io/docs/connect/registration/service-registration#expose-paths-configuration-reference>. I should note that these ports are exposed using the same sidecar proxy that is deployed for your application's service traffic. Consul does not require a separate proxy process to expose these ports.